# create new column based on rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue. I need to creat a new column based on row values.
so my table is

```
id | Name   |  status |   
-+-------+-------
1  | ANNA   |  M      | 
1  | anna   | null    | 
2  | DIVA   | null    | 
2  | diva   | null    |
```

based on the status column I want to create a column new_status. where it will check if the id is same and the value of any row of status column is non null then the new column would have that non null value otherwise it will be null. like the image below

```
id | Name   |  status | new_status
--+------+-------+------------
1  | ANNA   |  M      | M
1  | anna   | null    | M
2  | DIVA   | null    | null
2  | diva   | null    | null
```

please help me with this.

Comment: Please post data as text not images. What rdbms are you using: mysql, sql server etc?

Comment: i am using mysql. I have tried to post data as text but it becomes very messy. that's why post it as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments, as you are not supplying the DBMS you use:

1. I assume your DBMS supports the `LAST_VALUE(... IGNORE NULLS)` OLAP function
2. I am shamelessly taking advantage of the fact that capital letters come before small letters. Otherwise, you would need a third, `sequence` column within the `id` values; SQL tables are *not* sorted by default, and I would `PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sequence)` then.

But, otherwise:

```
\pset null (null)
WITH
indata(id,nam,status) AS (
            SELECT 1,'ANNA','M'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,'anna',NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,'DIVA',NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,'diva',NULL
)
SELECT
  *
, LAST_VALUE(status IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY nam) AS new_status
FROM indata
ORDER BY id,nam;

-- out Null display is "(null)".
-- out  id | nam  | status | new_status 
-- out ----+------+--------+------------
-- out   1 | ANNA | M      | M
-- out   1 | anna | (null) | M
-- out   2 | DIVA | (null) | (null)
-- out   2 | diva | (null) | (null)
```